# Prevent label of another data from being toggled whenever a label from one data is toggled

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a pie chart with two data, with two buttons used to toggle between the data. Everything works fine except for whenever I click a label from one data (either to hide or show the label and data), the label of the other data is also toggled.

For example, in the provided code below, under `Data 1`, if I click on label `Red` to hide it, then click the button `Data 2` to show the other data, `Apple` is also hidden. How can I prevent the other data's label (`Apple`, etc.) from being toggled whenever I click on one label (`Red`, etc.)?:

```js
var chartCanvas = document.getElementById("pie-chart");

var data1 = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
var data2 = [45, 8, 3, 1, 13, 53];

var labels1 = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];
var labels2 = ['Apple', 'Berry', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange'];

// chart.js initialize:
var ctx = chartCanvas.getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: "pie",
 data: {
  labels: labels1,
  datasets: [
  {
   label: "Data 1",
   data: data1,
   labels: labels1,
   backgroundColor: [
     'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
         ],
        }
     ],
 },
 options: {
  legend: {
   display: true,
   position: "bottom"
  },
  title: {
   display: true,
   text: "Data 1"
  }
 }
});

// pie chart buttons:

var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");

 btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = "Data 1";
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data1;
  myChart.data.labels = labels1;
  myChart.options.title.text = "Data 1";
  myChart.update();
 });

 btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = "Data 2";
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data2;
  myChart.data.labels = labels2;
  myChart.options.title.text = "Data 2";
  myChart.update();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
<button id="button1">Data 1</button>
<button id="button2">Data 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct API. But one way you could do it is to reset the `hidden` property on the metadata.

```
function resetLegends() {
  myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach(item => item.hidden = false);
}
```

```js
var chartCanvas = document.getElementById("pie-chart");

var data1 = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
var data2 = [45, 8, 3, 1, 13, 53];

var labels1 = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];
var labels2 = ['Apple', 'Berry', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange'];

// chart.js initialize:
var ctx = chartCanvas.getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: labels1,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data 1",
      data: data1,
      labels: labels1,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom"
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Data 1"
    }
  }
});

// pie chart buttons:

var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = "Data 1";
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data1;
  myChart.data.labels = labels1;
  myChart.options.title.text = "Data 1";
  resetLegends();
  myChart.update();
});

btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = "Data 2";
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data2;
  myChart.data.labels = labels2;
  myChart.options.title.text = "Data 2";
  resetLegends();
  myChart.update();
});

function resetLegends() {
  myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach(item => item.hidden = false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
<button id="button1">Data 1</button>
<button id="button2">Data 2</button>
```

Got some inspiration from the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions) and the source code of the default [onClick](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/feeda5d0344847e77cdeb899dc4db4182c321b85/src/controllers/controller.polarArea.js#L80) legend option.